# Eclipse android error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

Everytime I start the emulator from eclipse, I get the following error in my console.

[2010-09-13 17:04:51 - DeviceMonitor]Sending jdwp tracking request failed!
[2010-09-13 17:18:49 - DeviceMonitor]Sending jdwp tracking request failed!

The application works fine, but I am concerned as to why I see this error. Please help

Comment: First Google hit for jdwp: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jpda/jdwp-spec.html

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is coming from the Usage Stats option. I just installed ADT, did a test run and got this error, as well. I went to Window >> Preferences >> Android >> Usage Stats then checked it on. Tried another test and voila! No error!

Kind of annoying, I can imagine...

Answer (score 1):

This is caused after the emulator is closed while eclipse is still running.
When you first run the emulator after starting eclipse, a connection is established between it and eclipse. This connection is used to send messages back and forth between the two programs, and so eclipse can track the progress of the emulator.
When the emulator is closed, the connection is lost, and any attempt by eclipse to send a message results in the error messages you describe.

Answer (score 0):

As Koby said this message comes if you close the emulator after running an application. First of all between successive application running on emulator you don't need to close the emulator. First before running the application you start the emulator by clicking window-->Android SDK and AVD Manager and click on the emulator you want to launch and click on 'start' button and then click on 'Launch' to launch the emulator. After the emulator launches unlock the emulator and keep that emulator minimized. And if you want to run an application go for 'run as android app' and you can see that on the emulator when maximized. After running that application if you want to make some changes in the application you don't need to close the emulator. you press the home button after running the application and keep the emulator minimized. Make the changes on the code and again go for running the application. Thus you can avoid that error message and save time for launching the emulator. if you got that error message then also the application will work properly but you cannot see the messages like uploading app-->installing .apk-->and the success messages. But these will be happening on the background. One way to overcome this is to restart the eclipse.